# Doing fetch statements inside loop javascript async-await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, fetch

Ok so i am trying to do an async await inside a for loop for fetch and at the end appending the result to a wyswiwg. I am getting clipboard data when user pastes in editor and looping over images to save on my server. First it obtains blob from the url of the image by fetch() and again uses fetch() to upload file to my server. This is the code:

```js
    const forLoop = async _ => {
        for (let i = 0; i < imgNodeList.length; i++) {
            const img = imgNodeList[i];
            if (img.src) {
                let src = img.src;
                async function fetchBlob(src) {
                    const response = await fetch(src);
                    const blob = await response.blob();
                    return blob;
                }

                async function fetchUrl(file) {
                    const formData = newTokenData();
                    formData.append("image", file);
                    const response = await fetch('upload-image', { method: "POST", body: formData });
                    const json = await response.json();
                    return json;
                }

                fetchBlob(src).then(blob => {
                    let file = new File([blob], "new_file");
                    fetchUrl(file).then(json => {
                        console.log('image');
                        if (isJson(json)) {
                            let obj = JSON.parse(json);
                            if (obj.status == '200') {
                                tmp.querySelectorAll('img')[i].src = obj.url;
                            }
                        }
                    })
                });
            }
            console.log('loop end');
        }

        console.log('execute html');
        quill.clipboard.dangerouslyPasteHTML(index, tmp.innerHTML);
    }
    forLoop();
```

But the image console.log happens at the end like this:[image]
How can i do it so that the code waits for the fetch inside loop to get over and execute the paste action in the editor once the entire loop is over.

Comment: You can't make the `for` loop wait. Its a plain simple `for` loop that pays no attention to the asynchronous behavior in the loop body. You could collect the loop body into a separate `async` function and then collect the Promise instances from calling it into an array, and then use `Promise.all()` after the loop to wait for all of them to resolve.

Comment: And mixing `async/await` coding with `.then()` coding is not a great idea; use one or the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you don't mix `.then`'s and `await`s; use one or the other. Mixing the coding styles makes it much harder to keep track of order of execution and what will what on what. The 12 lines starting with `fetchBlob(src)` are *creating* a promise, but the don't actually wait for it.

Instead, you should change those lines to:

```
const blob = await fetchBlob(src);
let file = new File([blob], "new_file");
const json = await fetchUrl(file);
console.log('image');
if (isJson(json)) {
  let obj = JSON.parse(json);
  if (obj.status == '200') {
    tmp.querySelectorAll('img')[i].src = obj.url;
  }
}
```

As a reminder, the `await` keyword can only be used in an `async` function, so make sure the surrounding function is an `async` function.

With those modifications, the for loop will wait before moving to the next value of `i`, and will thus wait before getting to `console.log('execute html')`

Comment: It gives an error for ``const blob = await fetchBlob(src)``. Error: ``Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word``

Comment: Can you double-check that the surrounding function is an async function? Ie, it needs to be `const forLoop = async _ => {`, not `const forLoop = _ => {` (and i'm assuming you havn't added any extra functions not mentioned in your question)

Comment: thanks i had to change it to async on the loop. can you mention that in the answer then ill mark it correct